# Eggs in path before PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

If I have packages installed from *easy_install*, the eggs are prepended to `sys.path` before the items in the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

For example, if I have an egg package called *foo* installed as well as a package called *foo* in the current directory, and then do this:

```
PYTHONPATH="." python
>>> import foo
```

This will use the egg version of `foo` instead of the local directory. Inspecting `sys.path` shows that eggs are placed **before** items from `PYTHONPATH`. This seems broken. Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure it won't pick up a package from the current directory? Normally the first entry in `sys.path` should always be the empty string i.e. it'll look in the current directory first.

Comment: No, because the egg loader *prepends* its path, so it ends up before the current directory.

Comment: It prepends before the other *site* packages, but the first entry in `sys.path` is always `''` when running interactively, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path). That's the case for me whatever the `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately this is done with a hard-coded template deep inside `setuptools/command/easy_install.py`.  You could create a patched setuptools with an edited template, but I've found no clean way to extend easy_install from the outside.

Each time easy_install runs it will regenerate the file `easy_install.pth`. Here is a quick script which you can run after easy_install, to remove the header and footer from `easy_install.pth`. You could create a wrapper shell script to run this immediately after `easy_install`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
path = sys.argv[1]
lines = open(path, 'rb').readlines()
if lines and 'import sys' in lines[0]:
    open(path, 'wb').write(''.join(lines[1:-1]) + '\n')
```

Example:

```
% easy_install gdata
% PYTHONPATH=xyz python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/Users/pat/virt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata-2.0.14-py2.6.egg']

% ./fix_path ~/virt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easy_install.pth
% PYTHONPATH=xyz python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/Users/pat/xyz']
```

For more clarification, here is the format of `easy-install.pth`:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./gdata-2.0.14-py2.6.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

The two `import sys` lines are the culprit causing the eggs to appear at the start of the path. My script just removes those `sys.path`-munging lines.

Comment: It's really irritating that the user site doesn't have priority when paths/eggs are added to `sys.path`. On a machine where I don't have sudo I haven't found any way to override system-wide installed packages with user-installed ones. That looks like a pretty serious flaw in the way `sys.path` is assembled.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the answer by samplebias, but here's a link to a bug report that gives the specific patch suggested by samplebias to fix this issue in setuptools: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distribute/+bug/821000

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `-S` command-line option to suppress `*.pth` processing:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'
python -S -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.main

You can also use `-S` with `site.main()` to delay `*.pth` processing until runtime, say to capture the original sys.path for appending:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(
  PYTHONPATH='' \
  python -c 'import sys; \
    sys.path.extend(sys.argv[1:]); old=list(sys.path); \
    import site; site.main(); \
    [ old.append(p) for p in sys.path if p not in old ]; \
    sys.path=old; \
    print ":".join(sys.path)' \
  $EXTRA_PATH $ANOTHER_PATH)

python -S ... # using explicit PYTHONPATH
```

- Start from explicit empty `PYTHONPATH`
- Append to sys.path explicitly with extend
- Import site and call `site.main()`
- Append new paths to old path and then install it in sys.path
- Print with ":" for `PYTHONPATH`
- `python -S` is desirable for later runs only using `$PYTHONPATH`
- `python -S` may or may not be desirable while setting `PYTHONPATH` (depending on if you need sys.path expanded before extending)

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like the following to prepend to the system path when running a top-level python executable file:

```
import sys
sys.path = ["<your python path>"] + sys.path
```

Often, the `"<your python path>"` for me involves use of the `__file__` attribute to do relative look up for a path that includes the top-level module for my project.  This is not recommended for use in producing, eggs, though I don't seem to mind the consequences.  There may be another alternative to `__file__`.