# python paths and import order

Tags: python

I really want to get this right because I keep running into it when generating some big py2app/py2exe packages. I have my package that contains a lot of modules/packages that might also be in the users site packages/default location (if a user has a python distribution) but I want my distributed packages to take effect before them when running from my distribution.

Now from what I've read [here](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html) `PYTHONPATH` should be the first thing added to `sys.path` after the current directory, however from what I've tested on my machine that is not the case and all the folders defined in `$site-packages$/easy-install.pth` take precedence over this.

Could someone please give me some more in-depth explanation about this import order and help me find a way to set the environmental variables in such a way that the packages I distribute take precedence over the default installed ones?

So far my attempt is, for example on Mac-OS py2app, in my entry point script:

```
 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = DATA_PATH + ':'
 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] + os.path.join(DATA_PATH
                                                            , 'lib') + ':'
 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] + os.path.join(
                                DATA_PATH, 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages') + ':'
 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] + os.path.join(
                          DATA_PATH, 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages.zip')
```

This is basically the structure of the package generated by py2app. Then I just:

```
 SERVER = subprocess.Popen([PYTHON_EXE_PATH, '-m', 'bin.rpserver'
                            , cfg.RPC_SERVER_IP, cfg.RPC_SERVER_PORT],
                            shell=False, stdin=IN_FILE, stdout=OUT_FILE, 
                            stderr=ERR_FILE)
```

Here `PYTHON_EXE_PATH` is the path to the python executable that is added by py2app to the package. This works fine on a machine that doesn't have a python installed. However, when python distribution is already present, its site-packages take precedence.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python searches the paths in `sys.path` in order (see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). easy_install changes this list directly (see the last line in your easy-install.pth file):

```
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

This basically takes whatever directories are added and inserts them at the beginning of the list.

Also see [Eggs in path before PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984523/eggs-in-path-before-pythonpath-environment-variable).

Comment: Probably the easiest option when distributing py2exe project is to distribute all your necessary modules and the pythonXX.dll along with it, so that it's a self contained package that won't be impacted by any currently installed version of python.  Another interesting project for you may be virtualenv (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: So distributing the pythonXX.dll should stop the process I just described by happening? At what level in the distribution folder should the .dll be? I'm asking because currently I am adding the pythonXX.dll to the package but that problem still occurs.

Answer (score 20):

This page is a high Google result for "Python import order", so here's a hopefully clearer explanation:

- https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path
- https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

As both of those pages explain, the `import` order is:

1. Built-in python modules. You can see the list in the variable `sys.modules`.
2. The `sys.path` entries.
3. The installation-dependent default locations.

And as the `sys.path` doc page explains, it is populated as follows:

1. The first entry is the FULL PATH TO THE DIRECTORY of the file which `python` was started with (so `/someplace/on/disk/> $ python /path/to/the/run.py` means the first path is `/path/to/the/`, and likewise the path would be the same if you're in `/path/to/> $ python the/run.py` (it is still ALWAYS going to be set to the FULL PATH to the directory no matter if you gave python a relative or absolute file)), or it will be an empty string if python was started without a file aka interactive mode (an empty string means "current working directory for the python process"). In other words, Python assumes that the file you started wants to be able to do relative imports of `package/-folders` and `blah.py` modules that exist within the same location as the file you started python with.
2. The other entries in `sys.path` are populated from the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Basically your global pip folders where your third-party python packages are installed (things like `requests` and `numpy` and `tensorflow`).

So, basically: Yes, you can trust that Python will find your local package-folders and module files first, before any globally installed pip stuff.

Here's an example to explain further:

```py
myproject/ # <-- This is not a package (no __init__.py file).
  modules/ # <-- This is a package (has an __init__.py file).
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  run.py
  second.py

executed with: python /path/to/the/myproject/run.py
will cause sys.path[0] to be "/path/to/the/myproject/"

run.py contents:
import modules.foo as foo # will import "/path/to/the/myproject/" + "modules/foo.py"
import second # will import "/path/to/the/myproject/" + "second.py"

second.py contents:
import modules.foo as foo # will import "/path/to/the/myproject/" + "modules/foo.py"
```

**EDIT:**

You can run the following command to print a sorted list of all built-in module names. These are the things that load before ANY custom files/module folders in your projects. Basically these are names you must avoid in your own custom files:

`python -c "import sys, json; print(json.dumps(sorted(list(sys.modules.keys())), indent=4))"`

List as of Python 3.9.0:

```
"__main__",
"_abc",
"_bootlocale",
"_codecs",
"_collections",
"_collections_abc",
"_frozen_importlib",
"_frozen_importlib_external",
"_functools",
"_heapq",
"_imp",
"_io",
"_json",
"_locale",
"_operator",
"_signal",
"_sitebuiltins",
"_sre",
"_stat",
"_thread",
"_warnings",
"_weakref",
"abc",
"builtins",
"codecs",
"collections",
"copyreg",
"encodings",
"encodings.aliases",
"encodings.cp1252",
"encodings.latin_1",
"encodings.utf_8",
"enum",
"functools",
"genericpath",
"heapq",
"io",
"itertools",
"json",
"json.decoder",
"json.encoder",
"json.scanner",
"keyword",
"marshal",
"nt",
"ntpath",
"operator",
"os",
"os.path",
"pywin32_bootstrap",
"re",
"reprlib",
"site",
"sre_compile",
"sre_constants",
"sre_parse",
"stat",
"sys",
"time",
"types",
"winreg",
"zipimport"
```

**So NEVER use any of those names for you `.py` files or your project module subfolders.**

Answer (score 1):

after importing a module, python first searches from `sys.modules` list of directories.
if it is not found, then it searches from `sys.path` list of directories. There might be other lists python search for on your operating system

```
import time , sys
print (sys.modules)
print (sys.path)
```

output is lists of directories:

```
{... , ... , .....}
['C:\\Users\\****', 'C:\\****', ....']
```

`time` module is imported in accordance with the order of `sys.modules` and `sys.path` lists.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wan to add that if a module you are importing has the same name as a module in the sys.modules list, you have to delete the module entry in order to use your own module. This is what I did: 
del sys.modules["your module's name here"]

Answer (score 1):

Even though the above answers regarding the order in which the interpreter scans `sys.path` are correct, giving precedence to e.g. user file paths over `site-packages` deployed packages might fail if the full user path is not available in the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

For example, imagine you have the following structure of namespace packages:

```
/opt/repo_root
  - project  # this is the base package that brigns structure to the namespace hierarchy
  - my_pkg
  - my_pkg-core
  - my_pkg-gui
  - my_pkg-helpers
  - my_pkg-helpers-time_sync
```

The above packages all have the internal needed structure and metadata in order to be deployable by conda, and these are also all installed. Therefore, I can open a python shell and type:

```
>>> from project.my_pkg.helpers import time_sync
>>> print(time_sync.__file__)

/python/interpreter/path/lib/python3.6/site_packages/project/my_pkg/helpers/time_sync/__init__.py
```

will return some path in the python interpreter's `site-packages` subfolder. If I manually add the package to be imported to `PYTHONPATH` or even to `sys.path`, nothing will change.

```
>>> import os

>>> # joining separator ":" for Unix, ";" for NT
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ":".join(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'], "/opt/repo_root/my_pkg-helpers-time_sync")

>>> from project.my_pkg.helpers import time_sync
>>> print(time_sync.__file__)

/python/interpreter/path/lib/python3.6/site_packages/project/my_pkg/helpers/time_sync/__init__.py
```

still returns that the package has been imported from `site-packages`. You need to include the whole hierarchy of paths into `PYTHONPATH`, as if it was a traditional python package, and then it will work as you expect:

```
>>> import os

>>> # joining separator ":" for Unix, ";" for NT
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ":".join(
... os.environ['PYTHONPATH'],
... "/opt/repo_root",
... "/opt/repo_root/project",
... "/opt/repo_root/project/my_pkg",
... "/opt/repo_root/project/my_pkg-helpers",
... "/opt/repo_root/project/my_pkg-helpers-time_sync"
... )

>>> from project.my_pkg.helpers import time_sync
>>> print(time_sync.__file__)

/opt/project/my_pkg/helpers/time_sync/__init__.py
```

Comment: that sounds pretty crazy! one would think just adding the "/opt/repo_root" directory would do the trick since your import specifies the rest of the package hierarchy. I am used to java classpaths - this seems very different