# Enthought python package import precedence

Tags: python, enthought

I am using a venv to install a newer version of the `elpy` package from PyPI than is available on the root environment.  Querying from `pip`, I see the following version for `elpy`:

```
~/python/standalone $ pip show elpy
---
Name: elpy
Version: 1.4.2
Location: /home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: flake8
```

However, using the interpreter gives me the root environment version.

```
In [4]: import elpy
In [5]: elpy.__version__
Out[5]: '1.3.0'
In [6]: ?elpy
Type:       module
String Form:<module 'elpy' from '/home/ipython/Enthought2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elpy/__init__.pyc'>
File:       /home/ipython/Enthought/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elpy/__init__.py
Docstring:
The Emacs Lisp Python Environment.
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

My `sys.path` is messy, and I have no idea how to clean it up (I've upgraded Canopy distributions in the past), but here it is:

```
['',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/bin',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jediepcserver-0.0.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/epc-0.0.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sexpdata-0.0.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyCifRW-3.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphtool-0.5.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/packages',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/standalone',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python27.zip',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/home/ipython/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/share/apps/python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/packages',
 '/home/wdkrnls/python/standalone']
```

How should I go about maintaining `sys.path`? Do I need all these .egg files for a Canopy distribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python paths and import order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586630/python-paths-and-import-order)

Comment: Hmm... the root site-packages are checked before my local ones are.

Comment: export the path in your .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ipython. If you haven't installed ipython in the virtualenv, the ipython executable that's being run will be the system one.

To check, compare `which ipython` with `which python`. The Python executable should be the one in the virtualenv. If bet that the ipython executable is the system one.

Comment: '/home/wdknrls/python/env/local/bin/ipython' is the location of my installation of ipython I get with `which`, compared with '/home/wdkrnls/python/env/local/bin/python`. Both seem to be local.

Comment: @wdkrnls - Well, nevermind then!  Did you use the `--no-site-packages` option when you created the virtualenv?

Comment: I think I told it to inherit from the site packages, because there are site packages I want to use, if I don't have my own preferred versions installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

The order of precedence can be found by printing `sys.path`

Comment: Yes, the precedence is wrong. What's the cleanest way to fix it?

Comment: What is your sys.path, and what are the values of environment variables PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME if any?

Comment: I've only got two directories in PYTHONPATH: /home/wdkrnls/python/packages:/home/wdkrnls/python/standalone. There is nothing in PYTHONHOME.

Comment: what is your sys.path?

Comment: I added `sys.path` to the question. It's really messy, but I'm not sure how to properly maintain it. Any tips?

Comment: Somehow you have commingled two python installations, a recipe for chaos. What do you get from `which python`, `which ipython`, `which pip`? And exactly what program (from where) are you running when you get the output which you describe as "using the interpreter"?