# Path Search in Python

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, conda

I would imagine that this has been answered before, but I could not find a thread for that describes the search process exactly. Apologies if I am wrong. I

What is **exactly** the search process Python follows for finding a module? What **paths** are considered in what order?  (e.g. `sys.path` vs `PYTHONPATH` definitions, `site-packages` etc.)

I copied below the information from [the link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) provided in the comments, the following, but I have the following questions:

- What is the `installation-dependent` default exactly?
- What happens if you have a virtual environment from `virtualenv` or from `conda` activated?

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586630/python-paths-and-import-order), I found [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) that may help you.

Comment: There's a [good video](http://pyvideo.org/video/1707/how-import-works) on how import works from pycon a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The answer your looking for is here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html at section 6.1.2.

According to the site it is

```
the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
the installation-dependent default.
```

Comment: Thanks @Donkyhotay +1. I have updated the OP with that info and questions based on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the docs you are looking for are https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html. Note that two other things to look out for are `.pth` files and user site directories (`~/.local/lib/python2.7`).

I don't know how virtualenv works. Conda environments should be thought of as independent installations of Python, so they have their own independent `lib/python2.7` and `lib/python2.7/site-packages` directories. However, things like `PYTHONPATH`, `PYTHONHOME`, and `~/.local/lib/python2.7` are global, so all conda environments will use them (which is why I personally recommend against using them unless you really know what you are doing).