# Specify path to specific python executable using conda

Tags: python, conda

I am using python and conda within ArcGIS Pro 2.2, but am running into some problems with virtual environments. I have cloned a copy of the Arcgis Pro environment (hereafter clone). When I activate clone in the home folder for the original ArcGIS environment (`C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3`), the python executable is located at `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe`. However, if I activate clone in any other location, the clone looks to the clone's home folder and activates that version of python (located at `C:\Users\RDCERWAW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\gee\python.exe`). This is causing problems because import arcpy works when I run the `python.exe` located at .\arcgispro-py3, but not when using the python.exe located at `.\gee`. Even when I modify the PYTHONPATH to include the path the `.\arcgispro-py3\python.exe`, the other location is accessed first. I could always start the clone in the `.\argispro-py3` folder, but unfortunately spyder keeps looking back at `.\gee`.

Does anyone know how to code conda so that it look in a specific location first?

Comment: I believe you have to modify the PATH environment variable, not PYTHONPATH, for Conda to recognize the right Python.  Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34030373/9987623).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `sys.path.append(<preferred path>)`, try using `sys.path.insert(0, <preferred path>)` instead.

From what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586630/python-paths-and-import-order), Python searches each path in the order it appears in `sys.path`.

Comment: The problem there is that you have to start python to do this. I need to do it at the command prompt (or within the conda environment), so that when I start python, it is pointed to the correct executable.

Comment: Ah, yep this is a path for the python.exe executable. Please disregard.

Comment: So I am not sure what to do with this question. I have solved my problem and posted the answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316029/arcgisscripting-module-not-found-in-python-3-5-in-spyder-ide, and I didn't have to solve the issue that I was running into in this specific question