# Why am I unable to import my own os module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-os

I am using Python 3.10.

1. I created a module `os.py` in a directory, `my_dir`.
2. I am trying to access my `os.py` using `import os`, from `my_dir` directory.
3. But it is loading Python's `os` module, not mine.
4. I inserted `my_dir` in `sys.path` as a first element, but still it's loading Python's `os` module.
5. I repeated the same with another standard library of Python 3, `datetime`. But it's working as expected. i.e., it's loading my `datetime.py`, not Python's.

Why does only the `os` module have this problem? Is it a bug in Python 3?

Comment: Not a good idea to shadow common Python module names.

Comment: Don't ever run to "bug in Python" as your first choice.  `os` is special.  It gets loaded before your script has a chance to run, so it's already in the module cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is there any way to see this module cache ?

Comment: The cache is `sys.modules`.

Comment: Also try `from .os import x, y, z`. You'll need to run with a command like `python3 -m my_dir.app` though, replacing "app" with the other file.

Comment: Thank you! sys.modules showing os even though its not imported.

Comment: Forgive my limited knowledge , but it depends on the order of import. See this link for more information . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586630/python-paths-and-import-order

Comment: Does that mean, you cannot have a module named "os" (I know its a bad practice, still i have my own requirement)

Comment: You can create it with a different name (e.g. `my_os.py`) and then use `import my_os as os`.

Comment: @TimRoberts _"os is special":_ Sounds more like a bug than a feature to me.

Comment: Implementation detail, not bug.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to import some module A that happens to have the name of some other module B, that its placement in the import hierarchy mean that module B is found first, then you need to use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) to clearly differentiate between the two from withing modules in the same package

for example, said you have

```
my_dir
    __init__.py
    os.py
    app.py
```

for app.py to use your os.py you do

```
from .os import X
```

Comment: Thanks! your reply helped. But there have a few more things to do: 1. if you have dir structure as: parent_dir => os_middile_dir => os.py, test.py. Then from test.py you can write "from .os import my_cwd" 2. Then goto parent_dir and run like: python -m os_middile_dir.test

Comment: yes, you should be able to do 1 and 2 provided that os_middile_dir is a python package, aka it include `__init__.py`

Comment: This workaround will work, but the actual problem posted has nothing to do with relative imports. It is specific to the `os` module which is special and always loaded when Python starts. If you try it with another package (e.g. `math`) simply writing `import math` will just work.

Comment: Thats true. my actual requirement was to bypass "os" module with my own os module. That is almost impossible I think. Still, I understood why I am unable to do it. Thanks for your time :)