# User modules aren't loaded first (Python)

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Pandas version 0.12.0 site-wide and a user needs 0.13.0. I told him to install it to his home directory which he did but when he types `import pandas` it finds the old module.

So I decided to print out his `sys.path` and noticed these paths in this order (others removed to keep this brief):

```
[
    '',
    '/apps/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/apps/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

]
```

The PYTHONPATH is showing up after pandas as well:

```
[
    '',
    '/apps/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/lib64', // this is the PYTHONPATH
    '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/apps/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

]
```

What would cause pandas-0.12.0 to be specifically loaded before anything else, even the PYTHONPATH? There are several other packages that exhibit the same behavior as well. All packages have been installed by `pip` or by doing `python setup.py install`; would either method cause such an issue? I don't think we've manually edited anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eggs in path before PYTHONPATH environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984523/eggs-in-path-before-pythonpath-environment-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the module search path documentation lists the priorities of Python's import sources: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path. According to this, `PYTHONPATH` comes right after the current working directory.

Pretty sure the high priority of pip-installed packages comes from certain `pth` files in your site-packages directory (however, I was not able to quickly find out the priority of these `pth` files compared to `PYTHONPATH`).  Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html which explains how these files work. There is an advice, which should solve your problem:

> This module is automatically imported during initialization. The
>   automatic import can be suppressed using the interpreter’s -S option.

PYTHONPATH survives `-S` (tested with Python 2.7.3):

```
$ export PYTHONPATH="FOO"
$ python -S
>>> import sys
>>> "FOO" in sys.path
True
```

I see that this solution is problematic in case you also need packages from paths set up by `site.py`. However, in that case careful adjustment of `PYTHONPATH` would still help.

Edit: this looks like a longstanding issue with easy_install/setuptools/distribute. It is known that these might *prepend* to `sys.path`, effectively overriding `PYTHONPATH`, which is often times undesired behavior, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distribute/+bug/821000. I am not sure whether current pip and distribute still have this bug, maybe you should update to the most recent version of these.

Comment: Doing `python -S` also removes `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `/apps/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages` from sys.path; I will try playing with the .pth files.

Comment: This is strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984523/eggs-in-path-before-pythonpath-environment-variable

Comment: This as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586630/python-paths-and-import-order

Comment: Ah, that may be the issue. If it is I'll close my question as a duplicate.